# Vue Navigation Guard Infinite Redirection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, guard

I have a navigation guard as follows:

```
import authConfig from "./auth.config";
 
export function authGuard(to,from, next) {
    const publicPages = [
      '/login', 
      '/register', 
      '/home', 
      '/forgotpassword',
     
    ];
    const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
    const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem(authConfig.USER_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);   
    let resetPasswordRequired = true
        
    if (authRequired && !loggedIn ) {     
        return next('/login');        
    }       

    if(loggedIn && resetPasswordRequired) {
      return next('/resetpassword')
    }

    else return next();
    
}
```

It works fine without the if block for resetpassword.

I cannot figure out why infinite redirect error occurs.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I would assume it's because resetPasswordRequired is always true? If you set it to false inside the if block before you return next('/resetpassword') does that fix it?

Comment: That did not fix it. I think by setting it to true before the if blocks was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a infinite redirect at:

```
if(loggedIn && resetPasswordRequired) {
  return next('/resetpassword')
}
```

As `resetPasswordRequired` is always true due to `let resetPasswordRequired = true` and while `loggedIn` changes to true, your code always ends up redirecting to `/resetpassword`.

An approach could be to store information in local storage during login, if the user really needs to reset his passwort and set this information to false, before you redirecting.

Another approach would be to save the state of `resetPasswordRequired` in a store and change it´s state before redirecting.

The third approach would be to manage the process of changing the password on your login page and recieve information, if the user needs to reset his password initial, from a database during login.

Comment: I think by setting the resetPasswordRequired to true in the guard was the problem.  That was used for testing.  I added it to local storage for testing and checked against that, and that solved the infinite redirect.  I appreciate the other approaches as well. I may rethink my logic on this one. Thanks